# convert a dict to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a defaultdict that looks like...

```
defaultdict(int,
              {" u'CAMILLE'": 10,
               " u'SAHARA'": 1,
               " u'JEREMIAH'": 114,
               " u'EDISON'": 9,
               ...}
```

I need something like...

```
[[u'CAMILLE', 10],
 [u'SAHARA', 1],
 [u'JEREMIAH',114],
 [u'EDISON', 9],
 ...]
```

both

```
firstnames = [lambda x,y:list(x,y) for k,v in firstnames.items()]
```

and

```
firstnames = [lambda x,y:[x,y] for k,v in firstnames.items()]
```

produce

```
[<function __main__.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<lambda>>,
 ...]
```

which is obviously not what I'm intending. How can I correct this code?

Comment: Why do you think you need a lambda here?

Comment: Furthermore what does this have to do with [tag:apache-spark]?

Comment: I thought that perhaps converting defaultdicts to nested lists might be common in Spark as certain transformations will result in a defaultdict... ie "firstnames = babynames.map(lambda x: x.First_Name).countByValue()" but then "firstnames.take(10)" won't work because defaultdicts have no "take" method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `lambda`s:

```
firstnames = [[k,v] for k,v in firstnames.items()]
```

or even shorter:

```
firstnames = [list(t) for t in firstnames.items()]
```

`lambda` creates an anonymous function. This means you have generated a list of functions that take as input two parameters (here `x` and `y`) and return a list `[x,y]`. The `k` and `v` are not even taken into account in your approach.

Comment: slapping myself in the head now for stupidity. working in Spark and forgetting that every calculation needn't include a lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

Using map will also work:

```
firstnames = map(list, firstnames.items())
```

Note that in python3 this will build a generator (so, as Willem comment says, its better to inmediatly use `list()` around the map call so the values are taken at the call moment).

```
firstnames = list(map(list, firstnames.items()))
```

Comment: Mind that the result will not *materialize*. If in the meantime the dictionary changed, materializing later will fail. You probably better call `list` around `map` immediately.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, exactly, ill add it to the answer